# Managed cloud alternative to zookeeper

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, apache-zookeeper

We are running zookeeper today for configuration management. In many cases, this is the only service we are running ourselves. We are able to find a managednoffering for almost everything from aws RDS, all cloud providers have managed redis, etc.

In AWS or Azure, is there a managed offering that can replace zookeeper?